# Linking a second jquery anything slider on a page to a different CSS

Tags: jquery, css, anythingslider

I am trying to use two anything sliders on one page.

I need to style them differently.

I cannot seem to figure out how to call to a second style sheet without causing the second one to override the first one altogether.  The URL for the site I am working on is:

http://e4dv3.businesscatalyst.com/home.htm

Answer (score 2):

give one slider uniqe id and reference that in your css:

i.e. put a `<div id="top">...</div>` around the first slider. then you can use

```
#top div.anythingSlider .anythingControls ul a {
  background: url("../images/someotherimage.png");
}
```

to override the default images and classes and it will only apply to the first slider.

You can check out http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grouping_nesting.asp for more info on nesting

Comment: Niko,  I just tried it and it works perfectly!  Thank you very much for your help!